# ArcGIS Pro: Raster Con fails with Error 010423: random temp file does not have valid statistics as required by the operation

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, con, error-010423

**What am I trying to do:** I am attempting to use the CON function in ArcPy to create a raster of all areas within my area of interest with an elevation between 1600 and 1650 meters above sea level based on USGS elevation rasters. This should be the most basic possible use case of Con. The area of interest is the entire Upper Clark Fork River Basin, which is about 5k square miles. In particular, I am attempting to run the following command:

```
ElevationRange = Con('USGS_Data\\Elevation\\Elevation',1,0,"VALUE >= 1600 And VALUE <= 1650")
```

**What is the issue:** I am getting a problem with Error Code 010423, relating to a seemingly random temporary file not having valid statistics, thus causing Con to fail. Here's the full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 1783, in Con
    return Wrapper(
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 55, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 1776, in Wrapper
    result = arcpy.gp.Con_sa(
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 512, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 010423: C:\Users\[My Username]\AppData\Local\Temp\ArcGISProTemp55164\xf92f2949_e223_41c4_a3c5_c5ac0f4453b5y0.afr does not have valid statistics as required by the operation.
Failed to execute (Con).
```

**My failed troubleshooting:** I looked into the file path, and this file that is referenced at the bottom of the stacktrace (begins with xf92) does not exist. I tried calculating statistics on the elevation raster via the build statistics and pyramids geoprocessing tool (which worked), but this had no effect on the problem. I continue to get the same error. I am at a loss for how to proceed.

Note: a specific tag for this error code does not exist, and I didn't have enough reputation to create it, which is why I used the generic "error" tag instead.

Comment: Consider DEM = Raster(parhtoRaster) before Con. You can use Con(R>100,1)*Con(R<150,1) afterwards

Comment: Also `DEM = arcpy.Raster('USGS_Data/Elevation/Elevation')` then `ElevationRange = Con((DEM >= 1600) & (DEM <= 1650), 1, 0)` Note use of  parentheses and the `&` instead of `And` as you need to use a [boolean and operator.](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/spatial-analyst/boolean-and-operator.htm)